# Anylogic: How to you make a random agent move to from state to another?

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I want to randomly select a `person` (agent) that is in `state1` and instruct this random agent to move to `state2`. I also want to change the random agent's `var1`(variable) value to "true".

I think that I should use `randomWhere(population,condition)` to select the random agent, but I do not know how to code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have an Agent type `MyAgentType` with a state chart `statechart` and a msg-based transition between `state1` and `state2` that triggers upon the String "change", and the agents live in a population `myPopulation`, then you can do:

```
MyAgentType agentInState1 = randomWhere(myPopulation, p->p.statechart.isStateActive(MyAgentType.state1));
agentInState1.statechart.fireTransition("change");
agentInState1.var1 = true;
```